# Compute average Latency between groundtruth and predicted dataframes labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two dataframes containing Groundtruth and Predicted labels. Let's pretend I have 6 class labels. Let's say these dataframes look like this:

Groundtruth :

```
|0|0|0|0|1|1|1|2|2|3|3|3|4|4|4|5|5|5|5|5|5|5|
```

Predicted :

```
|0|0|0|1|1|1|1|1|2|3|3|4|4|4|5|5|5|5|5|5|5|5|
```

If the temporal interval between the frame from which the action begins and the frame where the classifier finally make decision is **h**, and the whole length of an action is **H**, then the latency of this action is defined as **h/H**.

Here's a figure that explains latency :

[image: Photo]

I want to compute average latency of classes based on these two dataframes.

Here's what I have tried so far :

```
groundtruth = pd.read_csv('groundtruth .csv', sep=",", header=None).transpose()
prediction = pd.read_csv('prediction .csv', sep=",", header=None).transpose()
    
average_latency=0
current_latency=0

changes_groundtruth = {}
changes_prediction = {}

for col in groundtruth.columns:
    changes_groundtruth[col] = [0] + [idx for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(groundtruth[col], groundtruth[col][1:]), 1) if i != j]
for col in prediction.columns:
    changes_prediction[col] = [0] + [idx for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(prediction[col], prediction[col][1:]), 1) if i != j]

    
for i in range(len(changes_groundtruth[0])):
    for j in range(len(changes_prediction[0])):
        if (changes_groundtruth[0][i] == changes_prediction[0][j]):
            if (groundtruth[0].loc[i] == prediction[0].loc[j]):
                current_latency += (changes_prediction[0][j] - changes_groundtruth[0][i])
        elif (changes_groundtruth[0][i] < changes_prediction[0][j]):
            if (groundtruth[0].loc[i] == prediction[0].loc[j]):
                current_latency += (changes_prediction[0][j] - changes_groundtruth[0][i])
```

I don't know if this correct or not. How can I compute latency the the best/correct way ?

Comment: You input is not clear, is it a Series or just the column of a dataframe? Can you clarify it by providing a Series/DataFrame constructor? Also please provide the matching expected output.

Comment: My inputs are two csv files. One containing groundtruth labels (1 Row x N columns) and one containing predicted labels (1 Row x N columns) like in the example.
For example, the latency of class label 2 is equal to (h=8-7)/(H=2)

Comment: OK, and what about the expected output?

Comment: If I correctly understood the given figure then latency for class label 2 in this example is equal to 0.5 (note that same action can be predicted many times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, and assuming `gt` and `pred` the **Series** of data:

```
gt = groundtruth[0]
pred = prediction[0]
```

You can use `groupby` on the Series themselves and `idxmin` to get the index of the first element and `size` the H, the rest is simple arthmetics:

```
g = gt.groupby(gt)
(pred.groupby(pred).idxmin()-g.idxmin())/g.size()
```

output:

```
0    0.000000
1   -0.333333
2    0.500000
3    0.000000
4   -0.333333
5   -0.142857
```